# Cannot properly power LEDs

Tags: power, led

I have two boards from the led headlights. Struggling to power it, I burnt one and now trying to understand how to properly power it.
Circuit itself looks quite straightforward: two upper LEDs are connected in series and connected to the pins 1 and 2. And bottom LED is connected to the pins 5 and 6. However I failed to turn them on.

[image]

I was trying to use different resistors in series with the LED but with no luck.
Eventually I connected it without resistor to voltage regulator and started to gradually increase the voltage from 2 V and above.

I used an ammeter to monitor the current. With 2 V voltage current was about 150 mA but no light form the led. Also I should mention that the board has a huge heatsink even though LEDs are only 3mm x 1.5mm. So step by step I increased voltage up to 12 V. Current was about 1.8 A (and heatsink was quite warm). But at some point I finished with short circuit inside the LED.

Appreciate any ideas about how to properly power this board

UPD: Also multimeter shows 0.7 V voltage drop on the LED. Is this normal? I thought typical voltage drop for high power LEDs is about 3 V.

UPD2: I replaced burnt LEDs with different ones and they work fine using the same power schema. My guess is that it somehow connected with LEDs themselves. They were 100% good and they are not IR. I don't understand why voltage drop on the LED is only 700 mV when for high power LEDs it's typical to have 3-4 V. So when I set voltage about 2 V (which is higher than 0.7 V) I have current about 200 mA already, but nothing happens. From my understanding it should start glowing event with 10 mA. Am I right?

[image]

Comment: Could these be IR LEDs?

Comment: Hella makes car headlights, probably not IR.

Comment: Yes, they are not IR for sure

Comment: Are you sure that you had the polarity correct?

Comment: @Mattman944 yes, I checked it with the multimeter. BTW it show voltage drop 700 mV. Also I replaced burnt LED with regular 1 watt LED and it works fine using voltage regulator. Also I don't understand why current is so big, when I set just 2 V, current is about 200 mV.

Comment: Are there traces on the rear side of the PCB as well? If so, please show the rear side as well.

Comment: @Huisman rear side is fully aluminium and should be attached to the heatsink. Also I manged to replace burnt LED with another one (3030 cree) and it works fine but the problem is that because of different size it's not in focus. Anyway, I don't understand why is this original LED behaves so differently from all the other chips I tested.

Comment: What do pins 3 and 4 do? Clearly they have components of some sort connected.

Comment: @Finbarr IDK, they are probably connected with another unit, but I only have this board. Pins 3 and 4 are not connected with LEDs and they only have capacitor and resistor connected in parallel.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there's nothing on the other side underneath that aluminium? I'm struggling to see why there are so many round solder pads if they're not plated-through holes.

Comment: @Finbarr Yes, I'am absolutely sure. Also I updated the question. I managed to replace these LEDs with other and everything works using the same pins (and the same components if any). Could it be some "special" type of LED or something like this?

Comment: High power LEDs are often run using PWM to increase the apparent light output without destroying them, maybe they have it built-in? Measure the voltage with a scope rather than a multimeter.

Comment: @Finbarr That "increase the apparent light output" is a myth. There is no free lunch. It's only for dimming.

Answer (score 1):

as you mention these boards are from Headlamps, with LED board did you find another board inside the headlamp?. because the board you are missing is LDM (LED Drive Modules). This is a self-contained power supply, that accommodates the LED’s powers. The modules have multiple channels to provide varying currents to different LED’s. These modules are used to power LED’s which are used to customize to accommodate the LED’s it powers. if you have that board, then you just connect the board with the LDM and give power to the LDM between 9V to 16V as it is headlamp it can take up to 6Amp of current approx, and check the results. if you didn't find the board don't worry, but you can still turn on these LEDs but **not recommended**. use the power supply in CC mode to drive the LED board.in my case, what I have done, I'll explain in brief, I have APlab 30V10Amp variable power supply, connected the LED board to power supply and I keep the current knob to 0 and start increasing voltage knob to around 6 volts as I increase the voltage PS goes into the CC mode then I started increasing the current the LED start glowing. it worked for me maybe it will work with you.
note:- do not run the LED for more than 10 sec. they are high power LED and without proper heat management the led may damage.